# Where to find auto reload code in rails source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in Rails 3.2 the code [from Active Reload](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload) has been merged in ...

"The most noticeable new feature is that development mode got a ton and a half faster. Inspired by Active Reload, we now only reload classes from files you’ve actually changed. The difference is dramatic on a larger application."

I was wondering if anybody knew where I could start looking to find the code that controls this behavior. I need to write some custom hooks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fa1d9a884c0d5b70c97442e3360ac98ca5fa4340) to see relevant changes.

Comment: Thanks Nick, a second question if you don't mind. I was using ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("active_support.dependencies.clear") to run some code everytime models were reloaded in development using the Active Reloader gem, but on moving to 3.2 it breaks ... I can't seem to find a hook to subscribe to in the commit you linked to. Do you have any ideas of what I could try?

Comment: I'm really not clear on how it works, was just able to dig up the relevant commit.

Comment: Thanks I eventually figured it out